# How do I use a select from a React component's return to make API calls?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api

My component currently looks as follows:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Table from "../../../../Table/Table";
import { getBalance } from "../../../../../datasource/Financials";

export default function BalanceSheet() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  startYear = ??;
  endYear = ??;

  useEffect(() => {
    const promise = getBalance(startYear, endYear);
    promise.then((data) => {
      setData(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return data ? (
    <>
      <h2>Balance Sheet</h2>
      <select class="select" id="currency">
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
      </select>
      <select class="select" id="startYear">
        <option value="2017" selected>2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
      </select>
      <select class="select" id="endYear">
        <option value="2020" selected>2020</option>
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
        <option value="2022">2022</option>
      </select>
      <Table
        theadData={Object.keys(data.data[0].facts)}
        tbodyData={data.data[0].facts}
      />
      ;
    </>
  ) : (
    "Sorry could not get data. Please try again."
  );
}
```

I'm hoping to pass `startYear` and `endYear` into `getBalance()` (which makes the api call) so that the page will automatically re-make the api call when a user changes either of the selects. Anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna re-render your component with changes of your variables you should set them as state and pass them as dependencies to your useEffect:

```
const [startYear, setStartYear] = useState()
const [endYear, setEndYear] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const promise = getBalance();
    promise.then((data) => {
      setData(data);
    });
  }, [startYear, endYear]);
```

```
<select class="select" id="startYear" onChange={(event) => setStartYear(evene.target.value)}>
        <option value="2017" selected>2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
      </select>
      <select class="select" id="endYear" onChange={(event) => setEndYear(event.target.value)}>
        <option value="2020" selected>2020</option>
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
        <option value="2022">2022</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but how would I get the values from the select though?

Comment: I added to the answer